# How to Add Effect to text when over it by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i need to add effect to text when mouse is hover is.

my js code :-

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {
j('.related_box ul li').hover(function(event) {
j(this).stop().animate({ right: "-5px" }, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
}
,
function(){
j(this).stop().animate({ right: "-75px" }, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
});
});
```

Html code :-

```
<div class="related_box">
<ul class="related_list_ul">
<li class="related_list"><h3><a href="#"></a><span>«</span> About us</h3></li>
<li class="related_list"><h3><a href="#"></a><span>«</span> Call us</h3></li>
<li class="related_list"><h3><a href="#"></a><span>«</span> Contact us</h3></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How to Add Effect to text when over it by mouse.

Comment: What's the problem, the code works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/VQja9/

Comment: Did you remember to include jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: Of course, you have to add easings (jQuery UI) and set an initial position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
j('.related_box > ul >  li > a').hover(function(event) {
```

Comment: Add some more explanation please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the element you want to animate is `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`, otherwise changing `right` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
li.related_list a:hover{ color: #xyz; }
```

you can do it using CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseover()` http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Example: (test here http://jsfiddle.net/y8GYq/)

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {

    j("li").mouseover(function(){
        j(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=50",
        height: "toggle"
        }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        }); // animate
   });
});
```